# Where are custom field values stored in the database

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the advanced custom fields plugin for posts. I would like to know where custom fields are stored. I checked the `wp_posts` table. However, I could not find the posts with  custom fields. I would like to know in which table are they stored in database.

Comment: Hello @ChetanaKestikar - since ACF is not actually a part of WordPress, it's difficult to say where it stores data without a great deal of knowledge regarding the inner workings of the plugin. For that reason, your question would be best addressed in the official ACF support channels.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the codex for [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Implementation_Details):

> The PostMeta information is stored in a new table, $wpdb->postmeta. This table has four fields:
>
> 'meta_id' - A unique id for each entry.
> 'post_id' - The ID of the post for this metadata.
> 'meta_key' - The name of the 'key'.
> 'meta_value' - The value associated with the key.

This of course assumings that ACF uses the default WordPress stucture and not a custom database.

Comment: So it turns out that ACF uses the default WordPress structure?

Comment: @MikeLyons You are correct.

Comment: But which is the name of the table?

Comment: @Revious From this diagram looks like `wp_postmeta` https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta

Comment: @BandonRandon: thanks, you are right. I've already deleted the unused one

Answer (score 0):

How do we know which ACF field is unused vs used?

This info for a custom field was listed in the "meta_value" field does this mean that there is associated content? It was a relationship field in ACF

**a:2:{i:0;s:5:"11637";i:1;s:5:"11463";}**

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258408)